# kolab 3.0 sources

Tags: aptitude

I'm attempting to install Kolab 3.0 following these [steps](http://docs.kolab.org/en-US/Kolab_Groupware/3.0/html/Community_Installation_Guide/chap-Community_Installation_Guide-Installation.html#sect-Community_Installation_Guide-Installation_with_APT_Packages) on 12.04 Server, yet showpkg still shows 2.2.4

```
:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kolab.list 
deb http://mirror.kolabsys.com/pub/ubuntu/kolab-3.0/ precise release updates
deb-src http://mirror.kolabsys.com/pub/ubuntu/kolab-3.0/ precise release updates

:~$ cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-kolab 
Package: *
Pin: origin mirror.kolabsys.com
Pin-Priority: 501

:~$ sudo apt-get update

:~$ sudo apt-cache showpkg kolabd
Package: kolabd
Versions: 
2.2.4-20100624-4ubuntu1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/au.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/au.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: c6d1151f02f88bd000b128ea0a4bf411
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/au.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: c6d1151f02f88bd000b128ea0a4bf411


Reverse Depends: 
  libkolab-perl,kolabd 2.2.1-20081212-1
  libkolab-perl,kolabd 2.2.1-20081212-1
Dependencies: 
2.2.4-20100624-4ubuntu1 - libnet-netmask-perl (0 (null)) libmail-box-perl (0 (null)) libterm-readkey-perl (0 (null)) libterm-readline-gnu-perl (0 (null)) postfix (2 2.4) postfix-ldap (2 2.4) sasl2-bin (0 (null)) libsasl2-modules (0 (null)) libkolab-perl (2 1:2.2.1-20081212-1) kolab-cyrus-admin (16 (null)) dovecot-metadata-plugin (0 (null)) kolab-cyrus-clients (16 (null)) dovecot-common (0 (null)) kolab-cyrus-imapd (16 (null)) dovecot-imapd (0 (null)) kolab-cyrus-pop3d (16 (null)) dovecot-pop3d (0 (null)) php-kolab-filter (0 (null)) php-kolab-freebusy (0 (null)) adduser (0 (null)) lsb-base (2 3.0-3) openssl (0 (null)) db4.2-util (0 (null)) kolab-webadmin (0 (null)) amavisd-new (0 (null)) clamav (0 (null)) clamav-daemon (0 (null)) spamassassin (0 (null)) slapd (0 (null)) ldap-utils (0 (null)) kolab-freebusy (3 2.2.1) kolab-freebusy:i386 (3 2.2.1) kolab-resource-handlers (3 2.2.1) kolab-resource-handlers:i386 (3 2.2.1) kolab-freebusy (3 2.2.1) kolab-freebusy:i386 (3 2.2.1) kolab-resource-handlers (3 2.2.1) kolab-resource-handlers:i386 (3 2.2.1) 
Provides: 
2.2.4-20100624-4ubuntu1 -
```

Answer (score 0):

The repository is still in testing so you actually need this source line to see any packages at all:

```
deb http://mirror.kolabsys.com/pub/ubuntu/kolab-3.0/ precise development
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through an install and used [this](http://mischa.beitz.org/node/131) process (http://mischa.beitz.org/node/131).

So far, so good . . .